# SQL Server 2014 Not recognizing Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. It didn't ask to create an instance at the installation stage. Now I am unable to login since its asking for instance name.

IIS is running but it's not displaying in the local server list. Also there is no instance running in the services.

I added `.` (dot) & `localhost` on the Login screen but still no luck.

Anyone has a clue?

[image] Studio 2014.

Comment: So you haven't actually got an installed SQL server? You'll need to go back to the installer and do that. If it is installed, try `(local)` if it's set up for named pipes but not TCP.

Comment: Check if the SQL Server service is running

Comment: Thanks for the anwer guys.  
I found the Solution, Installing the SQL Server Management studio alone will not help it. We need to install the SQL from below link microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and now i was able to install an Instance and now its showing in the Local Server list. –

Comment: The default instance, in case you install SQLExpress is called `SQLExpress`. Try seeing if you can connect to `localhost\sqlexpress`.